# Async communication between HTML page and Flask Python App

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm developing a single page application, which is represented by a map from Leaflet. When the page loads, asks to the user for the location, and zoom on it: it's fine. But when in my javascript script I receive the user location, I would like to call a python function, which returns places near the user, and put them on the map, possibly in an asynchronous way.
I don't refuse another solution, which is a welcome webpage, and on a button click the html page fetch user location, and on result navigate to the page with the map, which now has the location to fetch user points of interest.
What I  have tried:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1 />

    <title>OSM map tiles simple webapp</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').fitWorld()

    L.tileLayer('https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">
    OpenStreetMap</a> 
    contributors, '}).addTo(map);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
    @quatrefoilbot.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home():
        return render_template('map.html')


    @quatrefoilbot.route('/places', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def getPlaces():
        data = request.json
        latitude = data['latitude']
        longitude = data['longitude']
        places = database.getPlaces(latitude, longitude, 50)
        return places
```

Comment: What does `database.getPlaces(latitude, longitude, 50)` returns? What is type and content of `places` immediately before `return places`?

Comment: It returns a list of mongoldb objects, with name, description, latitude and longitude. In python those objects are simple dict

Comment: You might consider `flask.jsonify` if it can be serialized to JSON, in usage it this case would be replacing `return places` with `return flask.jsonify(places)` or `return jsonify(places)` (depending on how you `import` things). Example usage https://www.kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that I don't know how to call python function from javascript and get the result

Answer (score 0):

You might use [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) object in order to send request to server and get answer, consider following example

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       window.alert(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "https://httpbin.org/post", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"hello":"world"}));
```

should pop window where you will get what you sent back and some information about request you did done (this is what [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) do, see their page if you want to know more). What is happening in above code: we are preparing function which will be fired at every change of state, however it does anything only if state went to `4` which means `DONE` (for discussion of states see [XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)) and response status is `200` which is HTTP status code meaning OK. Then we are informing that we will do `POST` request, where to send it and that it be asynchronous (non-blocking), then that we will send JSON in request, which we finally `send`.